# SystemServerCAMSecurityRequired error when authenticating using Cognos

Tags: cognos-tm1

I am using the Cognos TM1 10.1 API to connect to a server. The server uses Cognos for authentication which in turn uses integrated login to authenticate users against our instance of Active Directory. I've tried using [`TM1SystemServerConnect`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ctm1/v10r1m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_api.10.1.0.doc/c_tm1func_tm1systemserverconnect.html?path=4_0_4_161#tm1func_tm1systemserverconnect) and [`TM1SystemServerConnectIntegratedLogin`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ctm1/v10r1m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_api.10.1.0.doc/c_tm1func_tm1systemserverconnectintegratedlogin.html?path=4_0_4_162#tm1func_tm1systemserverconnectintegratedlogin), but they both produce an error.

*(note that I've used pseduo-code for simplicity - yes, I've verified all the handles, inputs, etc, are correct and accurate)*

```
// Standard login
TM1V pLogin = TM1ValuePool( hUser );
TM1V hServerName = TM1ValString( pLogin, "server", 0 );
TM1V hUser = TM1ValString( pLogin, "userid", 0 );
TM1V hPassword = TM1ValString( pLogin, "password", 0 );
TM1SystemServerConnect( pLogin, hServerName, hUser, hPassword )
```

```
// Integrated Login
TM1V pLogin = TM1ValuePool( hUser );
TM1V hServerName = TM1ValString( pLogin, "server", 0 );
TM1V hServer = TM1SystemServerConnectIntegratedLogin( pLogin, hServerName );
```

The handle I get back from both (hServer) points to an error with code `199` and the message `SystemServerCAMSecurityRequired`. I've search through IBM's [TM1 API Guide](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ctm1/v10r1m0/nav/4_0) and I can't find a solution (or any documentation for this error message)... what's going on? The logs on the server show failed login attemtps, but provide no additional information.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the two documented login functions used above are specificaly for [IntegratedSecurityMode](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ctm1/v10r1m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_inst.10.1.1.doc/c_integratedsecuritymode_param_n0437.html?path=0_3_22_2_33#IntegratedSecurityMode_param_N0437) 1, 2 and 3.

You've indicated that you are using Cognos to handle user authentication, which is either mode 4 or 5. There are two more-or-less "undocumented" functions for logging in to the server using Cognos authentication:

- [`TM1SystemServerConnectWithCAMNamespace`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21576523)
- [`TM1SystemServerConnectWithCAMPassport`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21576522)

Here's a sample, written in C++ (copied from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418355)) which you can use a reference for connecting using Cognos authentication:

```
TM1V voServerName = TM1ValStringW( hPool, (TM1_UTF16_T *)pszServerName, 0 );

TM1V voPasswd = TM1ValStringEncryptW( hPool, (TM1_UTF16_T*)pszPassword, 0 );

TM1V vArray[3];
vArray[0] = TM1ValStringW( hPool, (TM1_UTF16_T*)szCAMNamespace, 0 );        
vArray[1] = TM1ValStringW( hPool, (TM1_UTF16_T*)admin_login_name, 0 );
vArray[2] = voPasswd;

TM1V vCAMArgArr = TM1ValArray(hPool, vArray, 3);
TM1V vTmpServer =
    TM1SystemServerConnectWithCAMNamespace(hPool, voServerName, vCAMArgArr);
```