# Cannot connect to server configured for CAM (Active directory hook) using the Cognos TM1 API

Tags: vba, active-directory, cognos, cognos-tm1

Is there anyway to connect to a server that uses CAM authentication in VBA using the TM1 API?

I've tried the following code based on the answer found here:
[SystemServerCAMSecurityRequired error when authenticating using Cognos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336817)

```vb
Dim credentials(1 To 3) As Long
credentials(1) = TM1ValString(hPool, Trim(CAMNamespace), 0)
credentials(2) = TM1ValString(hPool, Trim(ClientName), 0)
credentials(3) = TM1ValString(hPool, Trim(ClientPassword), 0)
vCredentials = TM1ValArray(hPool, credentials, 3)
hServer = TM1SystemServerConnectWithCAMNamespace(hPool, vServerName, vCredentials)
```

However, this causes Excel to crash.

I know I'm connecting to the correct server and I know the usernames / passwords are correct, I know that the TM1 API is installed correctly on my computer as well.

Comment: Don't have Cognos in my environment to test, but what's `hPool`? Does `TM1ValString` really returns a Long data type? At which line Excel crashes on (step through it)?

Comment: hPool is the reference to the connection, the way the API works is that all function calls return what is effectively a pointer (I'm assuming) that is represented as a long. You can then use another function to grab the actual values. 

If you would like I can create a more complete example.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Blake. There is no need for more complete example as there won't be any cognos server in the workplace. Wish you luck getting it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this solution based on dialog between IBM customer support and I.

It requires you add the following declare function:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function TM1SystemServerConnectWithCAMNamespace Lib "tm1api.dll" (ByVal hPool As Long, ByVal vServerName As Long, ByVal vCAMArr As Long) As Long
```

The login code:

```
Dim hArray As Long
Dim lArray(3) As Long

'Login to TM1 using CAM authentication
hArray = TM1ValArray(hPool, lArray(), 3)
TM1ValArraySet hArray, TM1ValString(hPool, "DOMANIN_NAME", 0), 1          
TM1ValArraySet hArray, TM1ValString(hPool, “TM1_USER_NAME”, 0), 2
TM1ValArraySet hArray, TM1ValStringEncrypt(hPool, “TM1_PASSWORD”, 0), 3
hServer = TM1SystemServerConnectWithCAMNamespace( _
    hPool, TM1ValString(hPool, "TM1_SERVER_NAME", 0), hArray)
```